# npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above

Tags: reactjs, npm

```
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! my-app@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the my-app@0.1.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Sonam\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-12-29T13_08_48_405Z-debug.log
```

I am trying my new react app in Visual Code, `node` is installed on the `C` drive, and the application is created in `D:\ReactJS\Project`.
Can anyone help with the above error?

Comment: Did you look at the complete log?

Comment: yes
below is thelog

Comment: 9 verbose lifecycle my-app@0.1.0~start: CWD: D:\ReactJS\Project\my-app
10 silly lifecycle my-app@0.1.0~start: Args: [ '/d /s /c', 'react-scripts start' ]
11 silly lifecycle my-app@0.1.0~start: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
12 info lifecycle my-app@0.1.0~start: Failed to exec start script
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:283:5)
\18 verbose node v12.13.1
19 verbose npm  v6.12.1

Comment: The question should be edited to include additional information--but you'd need to include *more* information, like what actually happened.

Comment: Did you run `npm install` before trying to start it?